# Spinner scrolls to default selection on touching in Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, spinner, android-7.0-nougat

I am using a spinner in my application, and a custom adapter to populate entries in the spinner. Everything works fine, like clicking on it, setting selection value, etc., but when I try to scroll on the spinner, the spinner itself moves to the default selection position irrespective of where it is, be it at the top or bottom, as soon as I touch it again to scroll, I am placed to the default selection.

You can find the adapter, spinner declaration and spinner item in the codes below.

Spinner.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
        style="@style/ToolbarSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start|left"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black_dropdown"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="test"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code that shows how I call the spinner adapter.:

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(mHelperActivity.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), item_list);
mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
mSpinner.setDropDownWidth((Utilities.getScreenWidth(getContext()) * 3) / 4);
mSpinner.setSelection(Caches.getSelectedCategoryPosition());
```

I have tried setting custom theme, custom popuptheme but to no gain.

P.S.: This only happens in Android 7, it works perfectly fine in Android 6 or less.

Comment: Where your entiries values for spinner >?

Comment: inside the spinner adapter call, named item_list

Comment: `mSpinner.setDropDownWidth((Utilities.getScreenWidth(getContext()) * 3) / 4);
mSpinner.setSelection(Caches.getSelectedCategoryPosition());`

please try to hash this line of code and try, i don't know why you commit your self with this way...

Comment: what do you mean by hash the line of code? and what way am I committing?

Comment: @BijonDesai Did you find solution to this ? I have the same problem.

Comment: Android 7.0 has some changes with the way how spinner works, we need to create a spinner in java and then addd it to toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove style from spinner

`style="@style/ToolbarSpinner"`

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I had the same problem and in my case it was using themes (popupTheme and theme)

```
   <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:gravity="bottom"
                     local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                     local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    >
```